# slick and quick proof martingale strategy even with added salary leads to bankruptcy

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, markov-chains, martingales, gambling

Assume James the employee initially has $X$ dollars in his bank and each day he makes $S$ dollars in his job.

After each day of work he then wants to make a supplemental bonus income of $B$ dollars, to do this he bets $B$ dollars, and if he loses he bets another $2B$ dollars, and then keeps doubling until he wins, unless at some point he doesn't have enough money for the next bet, in which case he cries (all of these bets take place during the same day).

Please note when he bets $B$ dollars he gets $2B$ dollars if he wins and $0$ dollars if he loses (we assume both happen with probability $\frac{1}{2}$).

What is a super short way to prove James cries with probability $1$ regardless of the values of $X,S$ and $B$?

I am also looking for intuition as to why the strategy wouldn't work.

---

Here is my lame proof: The probability James doubles his money after reaching $K$ dollars is equal to the probability he has $D=\lceil\frac{K}{S+B}\rceil$ succesful days. In order for a day to be succesful he cannot lose more than $L=\lceil\log_2(\frac{K}{B}) +2\rceil$ times. Notice there is $C$ so that $D> 2^{L}/C$ for all $K$

Hence the probability of doubling is at most $(1-(\frac{1}{2})^L) ^ {2^{L}/C}$. This quantity is at most $e^{-(\frac{1}{2})^L(2^L/C)}= e^{-\frac{1}{C}}$. Therefore we double only a finite number of times with probability $1$.

Comment: Is one bet placed per day?

Comment: No, each day you do all of the bets that are needed to get that extra $B$ dollars.

Comment: You're looking for "intuition for why the strategy wouldn't work," but wouldn't it? I thought this was the reason why at casinos they have table limit (lows and highs), so that you cannot start bets at $1 and just keep doubling them. I think if you could, and you had a big enough bank, and the odds actually were 50/50 (which of course they wouldn't be), then you could make money from casinos using this strategy with very little risk.

Comment: @Joe I think the reason why casinos do that is to manage their own risk, not to avoid a martingale of this sort, also casinos always play games in which the expected value is strictly in their favor, I think the situation for casinos is different.

Comment: Makes sense. And my "very little risk" statement seems naive. I was thinking that, given a large enough bank - say \$1B (fixed, $S=0$) - you could make \$1K/day, and your probability of losing after 10,000 days of playing would only be $\approx 1\%$. But that would still mean that you had a $1\%$ chance of losing \$1B and a $99\%$ chance of winning \$10M, which has a large variance.